# Initialising a multi dimension array to zero in C++

Tags: c++

I am initializing a 2D array to zero by `int a[4][4]={0}` and when i print it, `int a[3][4]=1,a[4][1]=a[4][2]=a[4][3]=1` and `a[4][4]=2`. What is wrong here? I want to have all the values set to zero.

Comment: Those aren't part of your array.

Comment: More explicitly, arrays of size 4 have indices from 0 to 3... so the last element you can legally access is `a[3][3]` (the first is `a[0][0]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `a[3][4]` and `a[4]` are *undefined behaviour*, since they attempt to access the respective array out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing data out of your array-boundaries.

Your array has the size of 4*4 (16 elements) because of this declaration:

```
a[4][4]={0};
```

When you want to access them, you have to regard the fact, that the lowest element in an array is `[0]` and not `[1]`. Therefor an array with the size of `[4]` has to be accessed over the indexes `0-3`.

The index 4 is out of your array range and will therefore lead towards *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

to reach the amount of a[4][4] you should call a[3][3]. numbers in computer are started from 0. [the number you you want] -1 = [the number you call]
& you haven't define any amount for a[4][4] that you have called, so it's an amount of other parts of your memory...